# Can Java programs in which null pointers are dereferenced be exploited in a meaningful way?

Tags: java, security

I'm writing a report for university and in one part I have decided that I need to take a stance on whether null pointers can be exploited in Java or not.

I found [this question on the Stackexchange on security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2379/is-there-a-real-risk-of-exploitation-in-java-code-where-a-null-pointer-is-derefe) in which the accepted answer says:

> Attacks based on null pointers in Java are theoretically impossible,
>   since the Java Virtual Machine handles all pointers, so it shouldn't
>   be a problem if you have a NullPointer in your code.

How true is this statement?

Apart from this question on Stackexchange I have not been able to find any resource or published paper which even discusses exploiting null pointers in Java.

This is not homework in which there is a correct answer, but I wouldn't like to say that exploiting null pointers is impossible in Java if that is not the case.

Comment: This is how true the statement is, still quoting from the same page you got it from: `This answer is absolutely wrong. There is no theoretical basis for saying that null pointers can never lead to a security flaw. Surely it is possible that a null pointer bug could lead to a security flaw if, e.g., it is part of a logic flaw in security-critical code.` Java only prevents a certain _class_ of null-pointer attacks, but since you haven't constrained your question to any such class, the fully general claim is false.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That comment is far less informed than the actual answers (which are pretty good in my opinion).

Comment: @VGR I wonder what you might mean by "informed" there. Dumping a truckload of low-level details doesn't make for an informed answer. The comment points out a correct criticism of the answer's thesis.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Perhaps this is purely academic, but I feel that pointing out actual possible attack vectors is more useful than saying “in theory anything could have a null dereference exploit.”  The statement is true, but not useful in my view.  The answers rightly point out that a 100% pure Java *program* is no more likely to introduce an exploit with a NullPointerException than with any other piece of code, though the native parts of Java obviously can.

Comment: @VGR The only good point is the one made by T. Hawtin, detailing a specific _kind_ of NP attack (exploiting a pointer+offset load where pointer is NULL and offset points to a salient address) and specifying that it's unavailable in Java. The longest answer just explains how JVMs deal with NPE, and the answer to which the comment actually applies claims that "NP attacks are _theoretically_ impossible", probably implying a specific class of such attacks, but not naming it.

Comment: I'd rather say that 'Null pointer exceptions should be downgraded in a risk assessment to a low or medium risk in modern systems' rather then using the phrase theoretically impossible that I would not use even relating my chance of walking on water.